# In codeigniter, var_dump($this) displays all the variables that are availible in the view

Tags: codeigniter

In codeigniter, If you use var_dump($this) you can see all the variables that are availible in your view. Database username and passwards are also visible. I am new to codeigniter, I do not know can this be misused or it is safe.

Comment: Please, describe what have you tried so far and where have you failed. Try to narrow down your question to one specific problem, now it's too broad for this resource, nobody is gonna do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
`var_dump($data)`
```

This is mainly used to display your structured information with type and value retrieved on your backend like model or controller etc.

Just refer the link to know more regarding [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and information on how to safeguard your credentials from [`var_dump(),var_export() and print_r()`](http://vancelucas.com/blog/hiding-variables-from-php-var_dump/).

Hope these reference's help you.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter we call methods using `$this`. So there is 100+ `$this` lines.

if your want to check value of some variable, You have to

1. **Assign value to variable**.

   ```
   ex: $array = $query->result_array(); //Model example
   ```
2. Then **check it using**

   - [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)
   - [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)